# Error on Xcode "No matching function for call to 'max'"

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors

This is the statement that I'm using but it says that no matching function for call to 'max'

```
max((used_minutes-Included_Minutes)*extra_charge,0)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

**Code**

```
 int used_minutes; const int Included_Minutes = 300;
 double total_charge, extra_charge;
 cout << "Enter the number of phone call minutes: ";
 cin >> used_minutes;
 cout <<"Number of phone call minutes used - included in the base plan: " << min(used_minutes,Included_Minutes) << endl;
 cout <<"Number of phone call minutes used - not included in the base plan: "<< max(used_minutes-Included_Minutes,0) << endl;
 extra_charge = 0.10;
 cout <<"Cost of excess phone call minutes: $"<<fixed << setprecision(2) << max(used_minutes-Included_Minutes)*extra_charge, 0) <<endl;
```

Comment: `std::max` and `std::min` are in the `algorithm` header.

Comment: I already used the #include <algorithm> but won't work

Comment: It would help if you would post a compilable example.  The call in your post makes no sense since it appears that you are trying to compare a pointer to zero.  Both inputs must be of the exact same type.

Comment: Please post the complete code

Comment: Include the declarations of the variables used in that line, particularly their *types*.

Comment: used_minutes and Included_minutes are type int and extra_charge is type double is there anyway I can put them together in the same expression in a max?

Comment: The result of multiplying an int and a double is a double. See the answer below.

Answer (score 30):

`max()` requires that the first and second arguments are of the same type. extra_charge is a double which results in the first and second arguments having different type. Try:

```
max((used_minutes-Included_Minutes)*extra_charge,0.0)
```

Comment: In my case only setting `0.0f` helped.